# Создание JS плагина

Tags: javascript, плагин, модули

Скажите пожалуйста.

Есть обертка для плагина. 
Как в ней правильно передать названия классов дальше?

Ведь оборачивать весь плагин в публичный конструктор window.Popup наверно не правильно? Или просто в переменную внутри конструктора сохранить и потом её передать наверно тоже слишком витиевато?

```
(function (window) {
'use strict';

  window.Popup = function(elems) {
    this.elems = elems.buttons;
    this.elems = elems.content;
  }

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   //Сам плагин в который нужно передать классы
  });
})(window);

let settings = {
    buttons: ".popup_button",
    content: ".popup_content"
}

let plugin_popup = new Popup(settings);
```

Comment: _window.Popup наверно не правильно_ - вполне себе вариант, вы ведь передаете только один публичный класс, реализация скрыта за замыканием

Comment: К сожалению не совсем вас понял. Публичных класса два .popup_button и .popup_content